# How to add complex Emergency Symbology (TrueType fonts) to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, font

In other packages I would simply ensure the TrueType font (+.ttf) was loaded on the operating system and it would be available for use.  QGIS seems to rely on making your own. The symbols I wish to import are complex Emergency Symbology that couldn't be recreated within QGIS.

How do I add complex Emergency Symbology (TrueType fonts) to QGIS?

Comment: I have used this technique for a map of water assets that I have created and it worked well. I created 16 different markers, so I saved them as a style for future use. Now I've had to go back, make a change to my map and reprint. I only get one symbol on my map. The full range of created symbols shows in my Layers List. I have tried to reload the saved style, I even went into each one and recreated it, then saved the layer again. The funny thing is that I have created the same styles for raw water as well. It is fine. I'm only having trouble with the potable water layer. Does anyone have any i

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I see you've added this question as a new question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81731/extending-how-to-add-complex-emergency-symbology-truetype-fonts-to-qgis) so that should get addressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS has a Font marker type which you can use.  It will support any (*most*) fonts installed on the system:

**In QGIS 2.0 (dev)**
[image]

**In QGIS 1.8**
[image]

You can even stack font markers like I have in the picture.

Comment: Thankyou it answered my question perfectly.  I'm a newbie and am still getting used to the terminology so missed the font marker clue.

Comment: No worries. Your MapInfo and ESRI fonts work in here too, which is handy.